# Burndown chart show as a red horizontal line even after spent time is updated

Tags: scrum, agile, jira, burn-charts

I am using scrum board in JIRA, I have customized column set.

```
    To Do 
    Development In Progress 
    Ready For Code Review 
    Code Review In Progress 
    Ready For Testing 
    Testing In Progress 
    Approved For Release 
    Released 
    Approved
```

instead of

```
new
in progress
to do.
```

In my burn-down chart, even after I added spent time or make the task approved, the burn down chart is shown as a straight red horizontal line, why is that?

Comment: The red line is all about estimated time. While logging work you can select to automatically reduce it. On closing a task you also need to set the remaining work to 0, if not you're red line will not have true declining behavior. So how do you "add spent time"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you should configure [Estimation and Tracking](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Estimation+and+Tracking) for your board.

Jira can track progress in either story points or hours:

- If you select Time Tracking *"None"* then issues will burn down their Story Points value upon completion.
- If you select *"Remaining Estimate and Time Spent"* the Burndown Chart will be based on *"Remaining Estimate"* and *"Time Spent"* fields.

***Board => Configure => Estimation***
[image]

Comment: Hi, I've configured this but the graph still shows a horizontal line even though time has been logged and the remaining estimate has been set to 0 when an issues is completed. Any idea why?

Comment: Check what is available in 'Estimation Statistic' field and read ['Configuring Estimation and Tracking'](https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/AGILE/Configuring+Estimation+and+Tracking).

Comment: @link64 in my case the order of column (in board configuration) crashed my graph evolution. When I puted back the status DONE in the last column the things gone back to work.